# SAPUI5 set JSON Model

Tags: javascript, json, html, sapui5

I got a bundle with some data I need:

```
"mpConfig": {
    "appId": "test",
    "isMock": "test",
    "mockServerPath": "test",
    "isDebug": "test",
    "isUnitTest": "test"
}
```

Now I need to put this in a JSON Model in order to be able to use this data. To retrieve the data I have my Controller class and the usage must be in a View class. How can I handle this problem?

I have read that something like this puts them in a JSON Model.

```
this.getView().setData(path().getConfig().mpConfig;
```

How can I use the data I got from the JavaScript class with the config mentioned above? Thanks for all help.

Comment: Try `this.getView().setModel(path().getConfig().mpConfig);` Make sure `path().getConfig().mpConfig` returns valid `object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below shows you how to create a new instance of a JSONModel and pass data to it. The data I use in the example is a JavaScript object. In case you have a JSON string instead make sure to call

```
var oData = JSON.parse(sMyJsonString);
```

The example below does not call this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->

        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="MyController"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">

                <VBox>
                    <Text text="appId          : {/mpConfig/appId}" />
                    <Text text="isMock         : {/mpConfig/isMock}" />
                    <Text text="mockServerPath : {/mpConfig/mockServerPath}" />
                    <Text text="isDebug        : {/mpConfig/isDebug}" />
                    <Text text="isUnitTest     : {/mpConfig/isUnitTest}" />
                </VBox>

            </mvc:View>
        </script>

        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";

                //### Controller ###
                sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
                    onInit : function () {

                        var oData = {
                            "mpConfig": {
                                "appId": "test appId",
                                "isMock": "test isMock",
                                "mockServerPath": "test mockServerPath",
                                "isDebug": "test isDebug",
                                "isUnitTest": "test isUnitTest"
                            }
                        };

                        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
                        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
                    }
                });

                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");

            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, you

1. get the data from somewhere
2. create an instance of a JSONModel
3. pass the data to that instance (I've done it in the constructor)
4. finally put the model on the view or where ever you want

That should work.

Comment: and I can use that in my Javascript Controller class?

Comment: Well, the code also has a controller. The relevant part for you is the code inside the init() function. You can use this code just like that in any controller. However, the data stored to oData is hard coded. Just change the hard coded part with whatever fits for you. That's it.

Comment: I got it. I need the part of the controller in my Controller, the data I posted there is from another Javascript class. And these datas must be put in the model in the Controller class and used in the view.xml class. How do I fix this?

Comment: And the path to the Data I get is correct, here shortened as path

Clarified: The data I posted above is from Component.js. These are reachable with a link I have. I need to use this link and put the data from the link in a JSON Model. May sound wierd but I don't know how I should clarify that :S

Comment: var oData = de.fum.nmp.Component.getMetadata().getConfig().nmpConfig;

        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);

Would this work, and how could I use the data now? Sorry for all those questions, just starting SAPUI5 :(

Comment: this.getOwnerComponent().getMetadata().getConfig().nmpConfig‌​ should work. Just use this.getOwnerComponent() inside your controller.

Comment: I don't know what you wanna do with the data, but typically you use the data in your view via data binding. My example code gives you an idea of how. Other than that I think you should have a look at the Walkthrough tutorial at https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db.html

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, use the data in my View. The data comes from another JavaScript class, if I use test.Component.getMetadata().getConfig().nmpConfig; (the path directly to the data) I get those data from the first post. In the Controller I have to put the data in a JSON Model and use it in a view then.

Comment: I was plain stupid, thank you for the answer. Still had to change some things but I got it